# Qemu show error when it use the parameter "-display sdl,gl=on"?

Tags: c, qemu

I want to use qemu with sdl.
But it will show error when I use following command:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
    -enable-kvm -M q35 -smp 2 -m 4G \
    -hda ubuntu.qcow2 \
    -net nic,model=virtio \
    -net user,hostfwd=tcp::2222-:22 \
    -vga virtio \
    -display sdl,gl=on
```

error is:

```
qemu-system-x86_64: Display 'sdl' is not available.
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Did you build qemu yourself or is it a precompiled package? Which version?

Comment: I build qemu by myself. Qemu's version is 4.2.92. Thank you.

Comment: Most probably you need to configure the build to include SDL support. You might need to install SDL and its development files. Qemu's documentation should provide help for this.

Comment: I can't find the Qemu's documentation talking about SDL. Thank you.

Comment: Which command can install SDL?

Comment: I add "--enable-sdl" to QEMU configure string. Then it will show SDL support(yes). But "Display 'sdl' is not available." is still there.